# Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest to verify website existence?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, http-response-codes

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that gets a foreign url, and attempts to verify its existence within 'tmOut' msecs. If verified within this timeframe, it should call a 'callback' function with this url as an argument.

Here is the function:

```
function chkUrl(url, tmOut, callback) {
  var abortChk = false;
  var abortTmr = setTimeout(function(){abortChk = true;}, tmOut);
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (x.readyState == 4) {
      if (x.status < 400 && !abortChk) {
        clearTimeout(abortTmr);
        callback(url);
      }
    }
  };
  x.open('GET', url, true);
  x.send(null);
}
```

Problem is because of cross-domain calls (probably) I get x.status=0 regardless of the url existence.

1. Is there a way to overcome/workaround the problem (without the users having to modify any default browser settings)? Alternatively, is there a way to achieve the same functionality otherwise?
2. Is this function "reentrant"? (can I call it safely several times for different urls at once?)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to overcome/workaround the problem

Client side? Only if the sites you are making the request to use CORS to grant you permission (which seems unlikely given the context).

Perform your test from your server instead of directly from the browser.

> Is this function "reentrant"? (can I call it safely several times for different urls at once?)

Yes. You aren't creating any globals.